# Typescript generics - restrict function parameter and return type to same type and infer type from usage

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to restrict a function parameter to extend a function where parameters and return values are restricted to the same type, without requiring the function itself to be generic.

I have a simple factory function which creates dom nodes with attributes, like this:

```
function div(className, attributes, children)
```

EventListener attributes (such as onclick) are restricted to either a function or a tuple:

```js
type EventHandler<T extends Event> = ((ev: T) => void) | [(ev: T, seed: SameType) => SameType, SameType];
```

Where SameType basically annotates that you should provide a tuple where the first item is a function which accepts a seed value, and a second argument which specifies the initial seed passed to the function once it is invoked.

I've tried to make the parameter itself be the generic, pass itself to a type and then using conditional matching, but with no luck. I cannot use generics on the interface itself as that would make no sense (onclick, oninput and onmouseover would all have different SameType seed values).

The function is inspired by Inferno's linkEvent function (https://github.com/infernojs/inferno/blob/master/packages/inferno/src/core/types.ts#L45), but instead of invoking a function you'd just pass in a tuple which I thought was handy, but the typing of it turned out a nightmare! Grateful for any input.

Is this issue related to the fact that Typescript disallows generics on the value level, or is there something I am missing? I'm thinking of [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574).

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick to the function on each handler. Ensuring on the `div` function that the `on*` attributes  have a tuple where the two elements are related in the way you want is possible, but not in a straight forward way.

It will involve capturing the actual type of the object literal passed into the `div` function and checking this custom constraint with a conditional type:

```
function div<TAttr extends {
  onClick:EventHandler<MouseEvent>,
  onKeyDown:EventHandler<KeyboardEvent>
}>(attributes: TAttr & CheckAttr<TAttr>): TAttr {
  return attributes;
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type CheckAttr<T> = UnionToIntersection<CheckAttrHelper<T>[keyof T]> 
type CheckAttrHelper<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends [(ev: Event, seed: infer P) => infer R, infer S] ?
      ([R] extends [P] ? [S] extends [P] ? never
          : Record<K, "Seed type is not assignable to parameter type">
          : Record<K, "Return type is not assignable to parameter type">
      ): never
}

type EventHandler<T extends Event> = ((ev: T) => void) | [(ev: T, seed: any) => any, any];

//ok
let a = div({
  onClick: [(ev, n: string | number) => 2, "1"],
  onKeyDown: [(ev, n: number) => n + 1, 1]
});

//err 
// Type '(string | ((ev: MouseEvent, n: string) => number))[]' is not assignable to type 
//'[(ev: MouseEvent, n: string) => number, string] & 
// "Return type is not assignable to parameter type"'.
let a2 = div({
  onClick: [(ev, n: string) => 2, "1"],
  onKeyDown: [(ev, n: number) => n + 1, 1]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really interesting workaround, I think I can make it work. The only downside is that it only typechecks, it doesn't infer types in the same way as template generics infer types (a method fn<T>(a: T): T will infer T from either a or the return value of the function). Even if you return 5, seed will still be any until you explicitly type it to number, or something else which then triggers CheckAttr. 

For VSCode linting of Javascript files, it's a lot more useful to achieve inferred typings as you get autocomplete without explicitly using JSDoc notations.